# Extract all occurrences of a string from table

Tags: regex, oracle, substr

I have data in my table column as below:

```
F35B: FIN#1                               
ID:          ISIN AB1051421L13               
F93B: Aggregate Balance                                                        
Balance:          55950000000,          #55,950,000,000.#     
F35B: FIN#2                               
ID:          ISIN BC1051421L13               
F93B: Aggregate Balance                                                       
Balance:          67950000000,          #67,950,000,000.#     
F35B: FIN#3                               
ID:          ISIN BA1051421L13               
F93B: Aggregate Balance                                                       
Balance:          76950000000,          #76,950,000,000.#
```

I need output as below:

```
ID                  Balance
AB1051421L13        55950000000
BC1051421L13        67950000000
BA1051421L13        76950000000
```

I tried using regexp_substr but its giving only one occurance. the source column is CLOB type.

Comment: It's unclear from your question as to whether that's multiple rows of sample data, or one row with a single multi-line string.  If it's multiple rows, please could you reformat the quesiton to make that clear, and any columns that allow you to know which rows are related to each other.  If it's a single row, please could you ***edit your question*** to state that clearly *(that you need to extract multiple rows of results from a single row of input)*?

Comment: its single row only. the data is in clob . we need to extract these occurrences into multiple rows as output.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here with capture groups:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'ISIN (\S+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS ID,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'Balance:\s+(\d+),', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS Balance
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine REGEXP_COUNT and REGEXP_SUBSTR functions to do that.
You need to generate required rows first (required_rows view), and then make join between your base table and the rows generated.
I optionnaly used greatest function to cover the case where the occurences were are not the same for both patherns.

```sql
with required_rows (lvl) as (
  select level lvl 
    from dual 
    connect by level <= (
          select max(
            greatest( 
              REGEXP_COUNT(col, 'ISIN (\S+)', 1, 'i'), REGEXP_COUNT(col, 'Balance:\s+(\d+),', 1, 'i')
              )
            ) 
          from Your_data
        )
)
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'ISIN (\S+)', 1, r.lvl, 'i', 1) AS ID,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'Balance:\s+(\d+),', 1, r.lvl, 'i', 1) AS Balance
FROM Your_data
JOIN required_rows r
ON r.lvl <= greatest( 
        REGEXP_COUNT(col, 'ISIN (\S+)', 1, 'i'), REGEXP_COUNT(col, 'Balance:\s+(\d+),', 1, 'i') 
      )
;
```

Here is a link to test it step by step.
[Oracle Live Sql](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/l4nvuibspcdiz75zob9sjgy88)

Comment: i tired using the above query as below:

Comment: Does it work for you or not ? Sorry, I am not sure that I got you well.

Comment: @MDO The OP has submitted an edit request to your answer, rather than editting their question to put the details there ***face palm***.  You can see their feedback if you click the `EDIT (1)` link below your answer.  My guess is that they actually have multiple rows in their table.

Comment: @Satya - Please don't put long winded feedback in comments, or try to edit someone's answer to put it there.  Instead, please edit your own question.

Comment: Thank you MatBailie.
When I executed my answer on oracle sql live, it works perfectly. In my local machine (oracle 11gR2) it also works perfectly. I really don't understand @Satya's comment.

Comment: I have the data in a column which is of CLOB type. When i tried to execute the query mentioned by @MDO i am getting error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: @MDO ,, I tried but getting the same error: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/l4nb5gkv3wnxuufqj3n5f47y7

Comment: @Satya, I got you now... In fact, if you have more than one row in your base table, you need actually to add a max aggregate function when generating rows in the required_rows view to avoid ORA-01427error. I made an update now to my answer, it should work with multiple rows. I would suggest you to put data for two at least rows as your sample data when you are asking questions in the future. I am so sorry to realize now where comes the problem when you test with your all rows.